# Object.Equals() method returns false on seemingly equal object

Tags: c#

I'm writing a C# application where I populate a `DataGridView` with a list of objects of type `Airport`. I'm currently writing the method to delete one after pressing a button.

For reference `dgvF` is a `DataGridView` containing the `flights List<Flights>`, I also have a dgvA for my `airports List<Airports>`.

```
private void bajaAeropuerto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String c = city.Text;
    String id = idAirport.Text;

    Airport delete = new Airport(c, id);

    //Select all Flights which reference the "delete" airport
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in listaVuelos.Rows)
    {
        Flight v = (Flight)row.DataBoundItem;
        Airport aO = v.fromCity;
        Airport aD = v.toCity;

        if(delete.Equals(aO) || delete.Equals(aD))
        {
            dgvF.MultiSelect = true;
            row.Selected = true;
        }
    }

    if (airports.Contains(delete))
    {
        airports.Remove(delete);
    }
    else
    {
        //show message airport doesn't exist
    }

    dgvAirports.Update();
    dgvAirports.Refresh();
}
```

However, the `if(delete.Equals(aO) || delete.Equals(aD))` and `if (airports.Contains(delete))` lines never return true, I run the Application on debug mode and although at one point `delete` is `{"TIJ- Tijuana"}` and `aD` is `{"TIJ - Tijuana"}` the boolean operation still returns `false`. I don't really know why. Is it because of my `.toString()` overrided method? Because I need it to display the full Airport name on my `DataGridView` of Flight methods.

My `Airport` and `Flight` classes are defined as follows:

```
class Airport
{
    public String city{ get; set; }
    public String id { get; set; }

    public Airport(String ciudad, String id)
    {
        this.city = city;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return id + "- " + city; //Ej. MX- Mexico City
    }
}
```

and

```
class Flight
{
    public String id { get; set; }
    public Airport fromCity{ get; set; }
    public Airport toCity { get; set; }
    public int price{ get; set; }

    public Flight(String id, Aeropuerto origen, Aeropuerto destino, int precio)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.fromCity = origen;
        this.toCity = destino;
        this.price= precio;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating a new instance before trying to delete it. Matching using `object.Equals` will be done by reference. That means that the 'address pointer in memory' is checked against the 'address pointer in memory' of the new one. That can never be true.

You should override and implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your class in order to influence the comparison.

```cs
public override bool Equals(object o)
{
    return o is Airport && ((Airport)o).id == this.id;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.id.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: I thought that maybe the problem was that I was calling equal by object reference instead of property values, but I read on msdn that .Equals() also returns true when called for two objects with different reference and same property values https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx is this untrue? Or I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: The default implementation uses `ReferenceEquals`... You should implement your own `Equals`.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misinterpreted the msdn example or something, I implemented the overrided methods you suggested and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. The static `object.Equals` calls the `Equals` on the first member, so if that overrides the `Equals` method, it does call that one.

Comment: @Ces `Equals` only works that way for `struct`s - if you change your `Airport` class to a `struct`, `a == b` will perform a value comparison, while on a class, it by default performs a reference comparison. You can override both the equality operator and the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods (you should always override all of them if you need to change one).

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` as Patrick has said, this is how I would do it:

Refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/336aedhh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx for more info.

```
class Airport
{
    ...

    public override bool equals(Object obj)
    {
        //types must be the exactly the same for non-sealed classes
        if (obj == null || obj.GetType() != GetType()) 
          return false;
        return equals((AirPort)obj);
    }

    private bool equals(AirPort other)
    {
        if (other == null)
          return false;
        return other.id == id; //only id should be needed if unique
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return id.GetHashCode(); //again, only id needed
    }
}
```

Or if `sealed`:

```
sealed class Airport
{
    ...

    public override bool equals(Object obj)
    {
        return equals(obj as AirPort);
    }

    public bool equals(AirPort other)
    {
        if (other == null)
          return false;
        return other.id == id; //only id should be needed if unique
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return id.GetHashCode(); //again, only id needed
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference link, I could be useful for me in a future.

Answer (score 0):

If the current instance is a reference type, the Equals(Object) method tests for reference equality, and a call to the Equals(Object) method is equivalent to a call to the ReferenceEquals method

```
  public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
  // Perform an equality check on two rectangles (Point object pairs). 
      if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType()) 
         return false;
       Airport r = (Airport)obj;
      return fromCity.Equals(r.fromCity) && toCity .Equals(r.toCity );
  }

  public override int GetHashCode() {
     return Tuple.Create(fromCity, toCity ).GetHashCode();
  }
```