# How to compare two objects when you can't override Equals?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, equals

I have an object `modelNoBend` of type `CalculationModel` and I have serialized it into a JSON and saved it in a `.txt` file using the below:

```
private static void GenerateTextFileNoBend(string path, CalculationModel model)
{
   if (!File.Exists(path)) {
      using (var file = File.CreateText(path + "noBend.txt")) {
         var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
         file.Write(json);
      }
   }
}
```

Then, I wanted to deserialize that JSON and check with the original object whether they are the same or not.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   GenerateTextFileNoBend(path, modelNoBend); 

   var jsonText = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\5113\noBend.txt");

   CalculationModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CalculationModel>(jsonText);

   string one = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modelNoBend);
   string two = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

   if (model.Equals(modelNoBend)) {
      Console.Write("Yes");
   }

   if (one.Equals(two)) {
      Console.Write("Yes");
   }

  }
```

> ```
>   if (model.Equals(modelNoBend)) - False
>   if (one.Equals(two)) - True
> ```

If I compare the two objects, `.Equals()` returns false. However, if I serialize them both once again and compare the strings, the `if` goes on the true branch.

Obviously, something that I have missed out on the last post is that **I can not edit the CalculationModel class**. This means that I can not follow the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599910/object-equals-method-returns-false-on-seemingly-equal-object), since I can not override `Equals`, nor use something else like `IEqualityComparer` as it requires the class to implement `IComparable`.

Is there any workaround for this, without me having to touch that class?

Comment: What defines uniqueness of this models? If all that public properties, just write your extension method for comparison.

Comment: Side note: `IEqualityComparer<T>` doesn't require `T` to implement anything

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Well, I actually tried doing that and I got an exemption saying that `At least one object must implement IComparable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you don't *override* `Equals` and `GetHashCode` then `model` and `modelNoBend` are
compared by their *references*. `model` and `modelNoBend` don't share the same reference, that's
why they considered being unequal.
You can't implement custom `Equals` and `GetHashCode` but you can implement *comparer*:

```
public class CalculationModelComparer : IEqualityComparer<CalculationModel> {
  public bool Equals(CalculationModel x, CalculationModel y) {
    if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
      return true;
    if (null == x || null == y)
      return false;

    // I have nothing but serialization data to compare
    //TODO: put smarter code: compare properties and fields here
    return string.Equals(
      JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x),
      JsonConvert.SerializeObject(y));
  }

  public int GetHashCode(CalculationModel obj) {
    if (null == obj)
      return 0;

    // I have nothing but serialization data to compare and
    // serialization is a long process... So we can put either 1 or
    // JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj).GetHashCode(); 
    //TODO: put smarter code: compute hash from properties and fields
    return 1;
  }

  public static IEqualityComparer<CalculationModel> Instance {get} = 
    new CalculationModelComparer(); 
}
```

Then use it:

```
if (CalculationModelComparer.Instance.Equals(model, modelNoBend)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! I have one question, though.. In the method `GetHashCode`, in the `if` - what exactly is `x`? What should I put there such that I do not get the error that `x does not exist in the current context`. Once again, thank you a lot! EDIT: Oh, silly me. I should have figured it was about `obj`...

Comment: @Arthur777: I'm sorry for the typo, it must be `if (null == obj)`

Comment: No problem at all! I was the silly one here!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer does not sound flippant; it is not meant to be.

If your use case is just this small case, or the class being checked for equality is reasonably small in terms of fields, it's totally legit to just code a method that compares the fields as needed.

There are plenty of cases that support something like this, especially in tight loops for performance.

That said @Dmitry's answer is correct. I offer this as an alternative when it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Kit. It does not sound flippant at all; I really appreciate your input on this. I agree, I should have thought of comparing the object's properties earlier. I just hoped it would be a nice shortcut, without seeing that the answer lays right in front of me.